# O meu entendimento sobre tags, o que são e como usar, está correcto?

Tags: debate, tags

A discussão sobre o uso das tags é importante mas, antes de eu poder discutir, necessito entender do assunto.

Não sei se o meu entendimento é correcto, por isso peço que me ajudem, comentando as seguintes afirmações:

- (1) **A função da tag é definir o assunto da pergunta.**
  ex.: `[concatenação-de-string]`
- (2) **Por vezes é necessário contextualizar o assunto.**
  ex.:`[c#]` `[concatenação-de-string]`
- (3) **Uma pergunta pode ter mais de uma "tag de assunto"<sup>(1)</sup>.**
- (4) **Uma "tag de contexto"<sup>(1)</sup> não deve ser utilizada sozinha.**
  Ou a pergunta não está clara ou é necessário criar uma "tag de assunto".
- (5) **Por vezes deve ser utilizada uma tag para classificar a pergunta.**
  ex.: `[sql]` `[sql-update]`. Apesar da segunda definir o assunto e dar contexto, a primeira permite mais facilmente seguir as perguntas sobre *sql*.
- (6) **Por vezes é necessário uma hierarquia de tags.**
  ex.: `[android]` `[android-studio]` `[app-compat-v7]` ou `[android]` `[android-eclipse]` `[app-compat-v7]`.
  O assunto pode ser o mesmo(configurar a api, p.ex.) mas é tratado/resolvido de forma diferente.

Justifiquem se tiver errada e/ou acrescentem outras se acharem relevantes.

<sub><sup>(1)</sup> As expressões "tag de assunto" e "tag de contexto" foram uma forma de facilitar aquilo que quero dizer.</sub>

Comment: Na verdade acho que todas *tags* são de assunto, o sistema de *tags* existe justamente para que não tenha algumas "melhores" que outras, com mais poder, com significado especial, a não ser que se queira fazer isso explicitamente, como ocorre no meta. Todas as *tags* devem ser usadas para classificação, para facilitar a busca e dar contexto. Nenhuma é usada de forma especial. Não chamaria o uso de versões exatamente de hierarquia, mas pode ser entendido assim. De uma modo geral tudo isso está correto e pretendo dar uma resposta bem completa sobre o assunto, talvez amanhã, hoje estou sem tempo.

Comment: @bigown "todas tags são de assunto" por achar isso também é que senti a necessidade de colocar aquela nota. Este *post* vem na sequência deste seu [comentário](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5310/precisamos-atualizar-as-perguntas-da-tag-atualiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o#comment19524_5311). Achei que era uma forma de facilitar("provocar") uma poste seu, completo e esclarecedor.

Comment: Olhando agora de outro ponto de vista (afinal precisamos tentar ver todos os lados) realmente parece que pode sim ser benéfico o uso de tags como `[concatenação-de-string]` e `[string]`, trarão dores de cabeça? Sim, mas ainda sim podem ser úteis, todavia ainda tenho de refletir (eu só não sei se os benefícios são o suficiente para compensar o outro lado).

Answer (score 2):

Vou dar uma opinião:

> A resposta original parece que levou a alguns entendimentos diferentes do que eu pretendia passar, por tal motivo vou tentar resumir ela de maneira mais clara.

Ao meu ver as tags devem falar especificamente do problema, sendo ele teórico ou não e podem ser sobre:

- **Tecnologia usada** (sendo preferencialmente a parte que falha, por exemplo se falha na parte php não tem porque adicionar a tag [html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)), note que tecnologia, pode ser APIs, frameworks e linguagem
- **design patterns** e **programming paradigm** (OOP, MVC, MVVM, etc), por exemplo, busca entender o MVC, ou então a classe não funciona como esperado, isso se foi você quem escreveu a classe e está com problema no uso ou criação dos métodos, variáveis, visibilidade, herança, abstração, etc. Se o problema for uma *exception* dentro de um método e que não seja falha do OOP, então não tem porque usar tal tag (todavia usa-lá assim não será nenhum crime :p).

  Agora usar a tag [mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) para se referir a uma exception no asp.net-mvc não tem sentido.
- **Software usado** para desenvolvimento, mas desde que o problema seja algo que precise ser configurado no software (se não tenha certeza então seria melhor adicionar a tag de qualquer forma), por exemplo se o problema é um erro em um código Java seu, não tem por que usar a tag [eclipse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse), agora se o problema for carregar um pacote no seu projeto então deve usar a tag.
- **Problemas é independente de linguagem** que geralmente são teóricos tem uma tag para isto, a tag [independente-de-linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/independente-de-linguagem)

### Destrinchar tags pra quê?

Agora o que não faz sentido é destrinchar algo que poderia ser apenas uma tag em multi-mini-tags para descrever algo que uma tag só faria, por exemplo a tag [sql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), ao meu ver a tag sozinha já fala de `UPDATE`, `SELECT`, `INSERT`, etc, não é preciso tags como:

- `sql-update`, `sql-delete`, `sql-insert`, `sql-select`

Eu citei anteriormente que acho tag [sql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) ruim, mas na verdade o que eu queria dizer é que raramente ela será bem usada.

Situações que ela pode ser bem usada:

- Se a pergunta for algo teórico sobre o conceito *Structured Query Language* (Linguagem de Consulta Estruturada ou apenas SQL)
- Se estiver desenvolvendo o seu próprio sistema de SQL

Não devemos usar:

- Se o problema for um erro em um query mysql, sql-server, postgre, etc

A maior parte dos casos as pessoas usam a tag [sql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) para isto e raramente irão usar para falar de SQL, eu concordo que a tag deve ficar, mas devemos ter atenção como ela.

### Tipos de tags que discordo

- [atualização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atualiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

  Isto é o problema que a pessoa enfrenta, por exemplo:

  1. Se o problema é ao instalar o VisualStudio, então deve estar no título algo como "Erro ao atualizar o visualstudio"
  2. Se o problema é ao atualizar o php o título deve ser algo como "Erro ao atualizar o php"
  3. Migrar um código, o título seria, "problema ao migrar código para o PHP 7"

  Mas usar uma tag somente para falar de atualização é totalmente nestes casos é totalmente redundante, o título nestes casos é o que deve estar bem definido, a tag atualização não é uma tecnologia, software, linguagem, ela é "o problema" que o AP enfrenta, se for assim qualquer problema que a pessoa enfrentar teria que virar tag.
- [configuração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/configura%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

  É bem semelhante ao problema da [atualização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atualiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o), a tag fala da duvida dentro de algo, se o problema é como configurar algo, isto é uma duvida do AP e não um assunto "especifico", deve estar definido no título, criar uma tag só para falar que estou enfrentando um problema de configuração é bastante exagerado, as tags neste caso pode ser melhor usadas se for a tag do software ou linguagem ao qual esta querendo configurar.
- [concatenação-de-string](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concatena%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-string)

  É outro tipo de tag que apenas indica o problema ou duvida que o AP enfrenta, é uma tag dispensável.

---

<s>- **(1) A função da tag é definir o assunto da pergunta.**</s>

Não, usar tags com este propósito abriria muitas brechas para criar tags para qualquer coisa, ao meu ver tags devem servir para definir as tecnologias (linguagens, frameworks, APIs, IDEs e plataformas).

> As tags de "design patterns" também podem ser usadas, por exemplo, MVC, MVVC, OOP, mas desde que a dúvida seja realmente sobre "design patterns". Se a dúvida for sobre PHP, por exemplo, eu acho estas tags muito redundantes, não fazem mal algum, mas não servem para nada.

- **(2) Por vezes é necessário contextualizar o assunto.**

  Não acho necessário, acho que deve usar o título e corpo da pergunta para isto.
- **(3) Uma pergunta pode ter mais de uma "tag de assunto"(1).** e **(4) Uma "tag de contexto"(1) não deve ser utilizada sozinha.**

  Discordo pelos mesmos motivos que descrevi no 1 e 2.
- **(5) Por vezes deve ser utilizada uma tag para classificar a pergunta.**

  Usando como exemplo, para mim a tag [sql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) já engloba UPDATE, SELECT, INSERT e uma tag [sql-update](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-update) é totalmente desnecessária. Na verdade indo mais longe, eu discordo da tag [sql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) em quase todos casos, exceto se você estiver criando o se próprio interpretador de queries.

  Para todos outros problemas, deve usar a tag referente ao tipo de banco de dados que usa, por exemplo: [mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql), [sql-server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), [firebird](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebird)

  > Fora que a maioria das pessoas usam a tag [sql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) achando se tratar exclusivamente do MySQL ou SQL Server.
- **(6) Por vezes é necessário uma hierarquia de tags.**

  Este é um caso que pode ser opcional adicionar as tags como [android-studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) e [android-eclipse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-eclipse), quero dizer só devem ser usadas se o problema for realmente com o IDE, se não for um problema com o IDE então a tag não deve ser usada, o melhor é informar no corpo da pergunta.

  Penso assim, pois a maioria pensa que coisas como Netbeans, Eclipse, CodeBlocks é que "fazem o código", mas na verdade são apenas IDEs configuráveis, se o problema é na configuração ou dependência de um IDE é valido, em todos outros casos eu discordo do uso deste tipo de tag.

Comment: Eu, sinceramente, não tenho tantas certezas como tu sobre as tags. Mas encaminho-me mais para esta opinião, sql-update parece ser desnecessária.

Comment: Será que MVC e OOP como tags ajudam alguma coisa? Ou mais vale ser informado na pergunta?

Comment: O que achas da tag [tag:string]?

Comment: @JorgeB. eu não gosto das tags MVC e OOP, porque são usadas em muitos casos sem necessidade, o que quis dizer que o que mais vale na pergunta é definir a linguagem e tecnologias.

Comment: @JorgeB. a tag `string` também é  redundante em minha opinião, não agreda em nada, mas não faz mal algum.

Comment: @JorgeB. atualizei a resposta :)

Comment: Mas então se não faz mal em nada, as outras também não. Ou é para todas ou não é para nenhuma.

Comment: @JorgeB. concordo, só quero dizer que elas são redundantes e são wikis desnecessários e eventualmente modificam o titulo da tag `<title>`. O que quero dizer é que o melhor é fazer o uso de tags para informar as tecnologias, claro que isso é opinião minha.

Comment: Claro e eu estou debatendo a tua opinião. Eu, por exemplo, não me incomoda muito a tag [tag:sql] porque sei que alguém que perceba de mysql vai conseguir responder a uma pergunta de sql-server. Agora a pergunta que fica é "será que vale a pena ter a tag sql?". Sinceramente, não sei. E a sql-update não será boa pra quem está aprendendo sql e saber as nuances específicas do update? Que pode ser crítico em programação? Estas perguntas deixam me muito dividido.

Comment: Pelo seu entendimento e se a tag [sql] não existisse, alguém que quisesse seguir/procurar perguntas relacionadas com a "Structured Query Language", teria de seguir/procurar as tags [mysql] [sql-server] [oracle] [firebird] e não sei quantas mais. Se o exemplo da 2 não usasse a tag [C#] e o contexto estivesse no título ou corpo, possivelmente eu não viria aquela pergunta.

Comment: @ramaral penso que este caso é totalmente exceção e tão raro que no teria no máximo duas perguntas, a maior parte das perguntas que usam a tag sql são sobre mysql e sql-server, e geralmente as pessoas não colocam a tag mysql, apenas sql.

Comment: O que você entende por "perguntas sobre mysql e sql-server"? Eu penso que a nossa divergência resulta desse entendimento. Há perguntas sobre mysql e sql-server que nada tem haver com sql, por outro lado, há perguntas sobre sql que nada tem haver com o motor do banco de dados.

Comment: @ramaral concordo totalmente contigo, é por isso que eu disse, a tag sql sempre será mal usada pelo mesmo motivo que você citou. Raramente ela será util. Não vi nenhum pergunta exclusivamente sobre "Structured Query Language".

Comment: Haverá sempre casos de má utilização de tags, qualquer que ela seja.

Comment: Nesta pergunta: [Query retorna nada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/148523/2541) que tags colocaria?

Comment: @ramaral definiria somente as tags da tecnologias usadas, que no caso colocaria as tags android e sqllite.

Comment: Colocaria porque o AP refere essas tecnologias. Se fosse eu(ou você) a fazer a pergunta não teria referido nenhuma tecnologia e a [resposta dada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/149579/2541) continuaria a ser válida

Comment: @ramaral ali foi um erro do AP, ele mesmo não sabia aonde era o problema, resumindo as tags se resumem a duvida e não necessariamente a resposta, uma pergunta pode ter inúmeras soluções, até mesmo com tecnologias não citadas. Todavia a tag sql não se encaixa em nenhum lugar ali.

Comment: Eu sigo a tag OOP e a acho interessante. Sim, ela frequentemente é mal usada, mas por vezes é usada de forma interessante e o resultado é bom. Existem muitas dúvidas sobre como OOP funciona, independente de implementação. Há espaço para ela. Penso que o mesmo valeria para MVC.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida eu não disse que não é para usar ela, pelo contrário, eu disse que são as tags aceitaveis, dentro da lista que coloquei no item (1), o que eu disse foi: As tags de "design patterns" também podem ser usadas, por exemplo, MVC, MVVC, OOP, mas desde que a dúvida seja realmente sobre "design patterns". O que eu discordo é de tags como `[configuração]` e `[concatenação-de-string]`. Acho que vou editar a resposta porque o pessoal tá confundindo muito.

Comment: Quanto mais se fala em tags mais eu fico confuso.

Comment: @JorgeB. A ideia é essa, "da confusão nasce a luz"

Comment: Acho que grande parte do seu ponto de vista desconsidera completamente a existência de perguntas conceituais e/ou teóricas. Além disso, ser tão avesso à granularidade (como rejeitar tags `sql-xxxxx`) não ajuda em nada a organização do site. Usei `sql-xxxxx` como exemplo do que estava no seu post, não significa que eu seja favorável à tag. Fora isso, concordo sobre a posição de que as tags tem que estar diretamente envolvidas com o cerne do problema (como você diz no último ponto). Acho que é fundamental nunca perder isso de vista.

Comment: Pessoal tentei atualizar a resposta para tornar mais claro, claro que concordo que os downvotes são contra-pontos e apoio isto, só que eu temia que tivesse sido interpretado de maneira errada, espero que agora esteja um pouco mais claro.