# Ajustar tag select

Tags: debate, tags, tag-específica

Notei que há muitas perguntas com a tag [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) se referindo ao HTML `<select>`, mas a descrição da tag se refere ao **SELECT de banco de dados**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Notem que inclusive há duas com o mesmo propósito:

[select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) e [sql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select)

E a que se refere ao HTML está como [html-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-select).

Acho que precisava padronizar e organizar isso melhor, pois geralmente quem quer procurar pela tag "select" para se referir ao elemento HTML, irá digitar "`sele...`" no campo de inclusão de tags, e não "`htm...`", por isso a confusão e uso incorreto da tag [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select).

O que poderia ser feito e quais as sugestões para podermos deixar isso "redondo"?

> Eu sugeriria alterar o [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) para [select-html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-html), porque
> geralmente digita-se primeiro a palavra "select" para buscar a tag, e
> excluiria a tag [html-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-select). E alteraria a tag [sql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select) para [select-sql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-sql).
>
> Aí ficariam apenas:
>
> [select-html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-html) e [select-sql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-sql)

---

### Resultados

Vou ir compilando aqui as opiniões/sugestões dadas. Por uma questão de organização, seria interessante deixar uma resposta com a sua sugestão:

> **@dvd**
>
> Eliminar [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) e a favor de [select-html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-html) e [select-sql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-sql)
>
> **@Guilherme Nascimento**
>
> Eliminar [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) e a favor de [select-html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-html) e [select-sql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-sql)
>
> **@Jefferson Quesado**
>
> Reduzir escopo e não a favor de [select-html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-html) (em dúvida)
>
> **@Victor Stafusa**
>
> Eliminar [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) e [select-sql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-sql)

Comment: Não sei se sou a favor de `select ==> select-html`. Mas que a tag deveria ser "reduzida de escopo" eu concordo. Também achei estranho essa navegação no nome da tag, primeiro a parte específica e então a "tag mãe", achei estranho cladisticamente falando. Estou acostumado com a notação binomial de Lineu, onde o "gênero/super-tipo" vem antes da "espécie/especificação"

Comment: Acho que esse debate não é pra curto-prazo, tem que esperar e ver mais opiniões e sugestões. Mas o quanto antes isso for definido melhor, porque tem muito usuário ganhando pontos em cima da tag "select" sem que a resposta se refira a SQL, o que ao meu ver, não seria o correto.

Comment: Eu já sou a favor de mandar a tag [select] e [select-sql] para o espaço. Não vejo nenhum valor nelas que a tag [sql] não traga.

Comment: Foi falado sobre eleminar a tag `select` e mudar `sql-select` para `select-sql`, mas por que não criar uma tag `select-nosql`? Pesoalmente, tenho muito mais dúvidas nos selects do Firebase do que em linguagens SQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu pessoalmente sempre fui contra certas sub-tags, por exemplo, a [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) atualmente se refere a instrução em sql, um exemplo em [mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql):

```
SELECT * FROM foo
```

Ao meu ver o ideal seria quando a pergunta for sobre o uso de `SELECT` o autor informar a tag do tipo de banco e talvez do tipo motor (se necessário este último), então a tag [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) é uma daquelas tags desnecessárias que raramente se tem necessidade real.

O mesmo vale para sub-tags como:

- [sql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select)
- [html-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-select)

Se a pergunta é sobre HTML eu pessoalmente não vejo a necessidade de se criar certas sub-tags, a pergunta geralmente já se engloba [html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) ou [html5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5), pois a maior parte dos problemas sobre HTML é algo bem mais amplo, geralmente depende de outras tags e css.

Se a tag é sobre a sintaxe `SELECT ...` como já disse anteriormente, creio que a tag sobre o **SGBD** seja mais que o suficiente, não tem porque ter uma tag como [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select).

Eu entendo a boa vontade das tags para sub-problemas, mas raramente mesmo vejo utilidades nestas tags, eu sou a favor de reduzir as tags, imaginem se eu tiver um problema com a propriedade `content` do CSS em pseudo-elementos:

```
foo::before {
     content: "conteudo"
}
```

Então eu deveria criar uma tag só para a propriedade, algo como [css-content](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-content)?

Creio que é um baita exagero, as tags servem para nos localizarmos e acho isto ótimo, mas duvido muito que alguém vai diretamente usá-las para algo, creio muito menos que alguém vai seguir tais tags ou usar o feed delas.

Creio que é muito mais provável as pessoas seguirem as tags principais, tags de versões e **tecnologias/propriedades especificas**, como por exemplo:

- [html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)
- [css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)
- [mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql)
- [oracle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle)
- [python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)
- [html5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) (conjunto tecnologias especificas dentro de HTML)
- [css3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) (conjunto de propriedades especificas dentro de CSS)
- [python-3.x](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) (tag de versão)

Eu não consigo ver alguém seguindo tags como a [html-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-select) (tag existente hoje) ou buscando perguntas especificamente nela.

---

No entanto se a maior parte da comunidade decidir acreditar que de alguma forma essas sub-tags são úteis, então creio que a sua sugestão é sim o melhor caminho:

> Aí ficariam apenas:
>
> [select-html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-html) e [select-sql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-sql)

Comment: Tb acho que tem que eliminar subtags.

Comment: Se eu entendi bem você só é contra algumas *sub-tags*. É assim ou, por exemplo, as tags `android-layout` e `android-recyclerview` não deveriam existir?

Comment: @ramaral basicamente isto o que disse, se a tag for muito usada então ela entra na exceção, por exemplo, se android-layout for algo muito procurado seria uma excação o que tornaria a tag muito útil, caso contrário ela seria provavelmente uma redundância, já que a tag [tag:android] talvez resolvesse... No caso olhando para ambas, android-layout me parece útil e parece que já englobaria android-recyclerview, então neste caso especifico e meu vago conhecimento nisto (e opinião) somente a tag android-layout é de fato útil, já a recyclerview é redundante.

Comment: Julgo que entendo o seu ponto de vista. No entanto, só é possível saber se uma tag é muito usada se ela existir. A meu ver o problema está mais no saber quando usa/criar uma determinada tag no que propriamente se deve existir ou não. As tags são criadas quando são usadas pela primeira vez, se nessa altura fui bem aplicada então ela deve existir.

Comment: @ramaral sim, mas a minha avaliação é sobre as tags existentes e não sobre as que ainda não foram experimentadas, tem tags que pelo baixo numero de perguntas associadas ou por questão de experiencia de quem frequenta as tags "parentes" já é possivel notar se é útil ou não.

Comment: Lembrei agora que a nossa "divergência" já tinha sido debatida nesta [pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5314/2541)/[resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5315/2541).

Comment: @ramaral sim, inclusive se eu procurar talvez tenha mais alguma minha que falo disto, no entanto é muito dificil explicar para as pessoas, tanto que tenho -3 lá, mas acredito que meus argumentos são bem sólidos, só não consegui transmitir bem eles ou as pessoas realmente tem muita estima (obsessiva) por certas tags e acabam por entender mal o meu posicionamento contra coisas que considero redundância.

Answer (score 2):

> Por uma questão de organização, seria interessante deixar uma resposta com a sua sugestão.

Se uma pessoa tem problemas para escrever uma query, o problema é para a tag [sql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql). A depender do problema, pode ser que a tage mais adequada seja [mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) ou coisa do tipo.

Se uma pessoa tem problemas com o componente `select` do HTML, então a tag deve ser [html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html).

Por isso, a tag [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) deve deixar de existir. É ambígua e redundante.

Não creio que precisemos de tags como [select-sql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-sql) ou [select-html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-html).