# Por que temos as tags [select] e [sql-select]?

Tags: debate, tags, tag-específica

Hoje temos a tag [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select):

> USE ESTA TAG APENAS QUANDO FOR SE REFERIR A BANCO DE DADOS. SELECT é uma declaração SQL que retorna zero ou mais linhas, de uma ou mais tabelas-base, tabelas temporárias ou views em um banco de dados. NÃO USE para se referir ao elemento "select" do HTML.

E a tag [sql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select):

> SELECT é uma declaração SQL que retorna zero ou mais linhas, de uma ou mais tabelas-base, tabelas temporárias ou views em um banco de dados.

Mas ambas têm o mesmo objetivo.
Não seria melhor agrupar tudo em uma tag só (sugiro [sql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select))?

Comment: se não me engano isso já foi dicutido aqui, mas não tenho certeza. Sim foi: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6851/ajustar-tag-select e nessa não é específicamente essas tags mas é comentado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5314/o-meu-entendimento-sobre-tags-o-que-são-e-como-usar-está-correcto/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não deveria ter a [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select), ela é ambígua a descrição dela deveria ser para não usá-la. E ser marcada como proibida, mas nunca conseguimos fazer isto. O correto é usar apenas [sql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select) e [html-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-select).

O problema é que para começar eliminar a [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) precisaria pelo menos tirar tudo o que é não é sobre SQL e quem sabe fazer uma fusão, o que poderia causar outros problemas. No momento mesclar ambas tornaria muita pergunta com *tag* definitivamente errada quando hoje é só ambígua. Voluntários?

Com a ferramenta atual é complicado resolver o problema de vez. Claro a solução melhor é seria as usuários serem mais cuidadosos, se importar com o que estão postando, mas isto também não vai acontecer. Tem hora que dá vontade de criar o sinônimo e usuário desatento que pague a consequência por colocar uma *tag* errada.

Comment: Mas então será que não seria melhor alterar o texto da tag para algo como: "ESTA TAG É AMBÍGUA, PORTANTO, USE A TAG 'sql-select' AO INVÉS DESTA."?

Comment: Sim, mas de nada adianta, ninguém lê isto.

Comment: Eu leio! :-) Eu postei a pergunta aqui no meta justamente porque encontrei uma pergunta hoje na fila que tinha as duas tags (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/340909/86952), e eu pensei em tirar uma das duas, mas quando li a descrição fiquei na dúvida.